# Размытие в input по клику

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, css3, design

Приветствую.

Как сделать размытие текста по клику в input?
Пример: https://webgradients.com/

Опуститесь в самый низ страницы, в разделе FOLLOW THE BEST кликните по Your email.
Когда кликните по input текст будет размыт.

Очень красивый эффект.
Пожалуйста, помогите его повторить.

Даже пример нашел: http:// jsfiddle.net/vx75r/3/ (удалите пробел)

Но как сделать так, чтобы было размытие после клика и дальше можно было вводить нужный текст?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

просто надо было открыть DevTools и посмотреть

```css
.footer__form
{
 position: relative;
}
.footer__input
{
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
 border-radius: 42px;
 height: 42px;
 line-height: 42px;
 max-width: 207px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 40px;
 transition: border-color .2s ease;
}
.footer__input::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
 color: rgba(106,105,105,0.6);
 font-size: 13px;
 transition: filter .2s ease, opacity .2s .2s ease;
}
.footer__input:-moz-placeholder
{
 color: rgba(106,105,105,0.6);
 font-size: 13px;
 transition: filter .2s ease, opacity .2s .2s ease;
}
.footer__input::-moz-placeholder
{
 color: rgba(106,105,105,0.6);
 font-size: 13px;
 transition: filter .2s ease, opacity .2s .2s ease;
}
.footer__input:-ms-input-placeholder
{
 color: rgba(106,105,105,0.6);
 font-size: 13px;
 transition: filter .2s ease, opacity .2s .2s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 500px)
{
 .footer__input
 {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
}
.footer__input:focus
{
 border-color: #333435;
}
.footer__input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
 filter: blur(3px);
 opacity: 0;
}
.footer__input:focus:-moz-placeholder
{
 filter: blur(3px);
 opacity: 0;
}
.footer__input:focus::-moz-placeholder
{
 filter: blur(3px);
 opacity: 0;
}
.footer__input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder
{
 filter: blur(3px);
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<input class="footer__input" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" placeholder="Your email" name="EMAIL" required="">
```